# Can I know the status of a post I flagged?

Tags: support, flagging

I flagged the second answer in [a question I asked](https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/9950/what-is-the-minimal-extension-of-fo-that-captures-the-class-of-regular-languages) because it is only a reply to a comment I left in the first answer. Ideally, there should be only one answer with an update, but the user is new and apparently unaware of the features of this website (like editing), so I flagged the second answer to see if a moderator could help me with that.

Is it possible for me to know the status of my request?

Comment: I don't see any current flags.

Comment: @SureshVenkat Perhaps somebody already did something? It was the first time I flag a post, and I don't know how it works. Do I get notifications or something similar? Can I see a list of flags raised by me? In any case, I can flag it again, if it is convenient.

Comment: It's possible the flag was dealt with. sometimes we clear flags if we don't think the issue is significant enough.

Comment: @SureshVenkat Maybe it wasn't significant for the moderator. It is significant for me, but definitely not urgent. If I edit the first answer so it will look like a merge, could you delete the second one?

Comment: @Kaveh: thanks for clarifying, but I don't know where is that response, and I haven't received a notification (maybe I missed it). That's why I asked if there is something like "my flags".

Comment: I moved my comment to an answer. I am not sure how exactly the flag feedback mechanism works, this was my first use of it. Hopefully someone else can shed light on how it works.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

IIRC, I cleared the flag and put a response to you in the system explaining the reason: there is no policy on this as far as I know, so users are free to post multiple answers, if you think they should be combined you should ask their author directly to combine them (which you haven't done yet) and not the moderators.

Editing other people's answers in a significant way is not uncontroversial. I don't remember any case of merging of answers in the way you are suggesting. Moreover, it is not uncommon to answer new issues that arise in comments in a new answer.

If you ask me what you should do if you want them to be combined, I would suggest asking the author to combine them. If the author doesn't want to then I suggest leaving it as it is. If you really want to have the material in the answers combined in one answer then you can post a new answer yourself (possibly in a CW one).

Answer (score 3):

To see the status of your flags, go to your profile (while logged in) under profile view, you will see a "helpful tags" header with a number next to it. That number is a hyperlink, click it to see the status of all your tags. @Kaveh's response to your flag should also be there.

[image: helpful flags link]

This link takes me to

https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/users/flag-summary/1037

Note that "1037" is my user number, so you will probably get a page-not-found error. Try replacing it with your user number.

Comment: I don't see anything of the sort...

Comment: @Janoma I will try to add an image to clarify. But for now, try [this link](http://cstheory.stackexchange.com/users/flag-summary/5396) I got it by taking my flag-summary link and replacing my user number by yours. Note that I get a page-not-found, but I think this is because I am not allowed to view your flagging details.

Comment: It works, but I don't see a link to that from my profie page. Thanks!

Comment: @Janoma no problem, maybe its a rep thing (although I can see my flagging link on other SEs where I have lower rep) or you just haven't made enough flags, yet. All that careful image making for nothing ;).

Comment: Update: I do see it now. Maybe it was a script that ran recently.

Comment: Thanks Artem for explaining the system. :)